# When I Transpile my TypeScript file, the variables declared in 'let' and 'const' are converted to 'var' in generated Javascript file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have even made manipulation in tsconfig.json (i.e. target) file.

I have set my `"target":"ES6"` in tsconfig.json as of now.

While I have tried various solutions, yet the transpilation is not working out correctly. The transpilation works out correctly when I just type `tsc` command in the terminal.

This is the code from 'data.ts'

```ts
const FirstName: string = "John"
let age: number = 23
```

and the generated 'data.js'

```js
var FirstName = "John";
var age = 23;
```

This is my file structure

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain when it *doesn’t* work since I only see you mentioning how it *does* work.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen when I run the command 'tsc fileName.ts', it is not transpiling correctly.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], including both your code and the config file(s).

Comment: @InSync I have  updated my query above with an example for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

The [`tsc` CLI documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) makes this clear — your TSConfig is ignored when you include file arguments to `tsc`:

> ### Using the CLI
>
> Running `tsc` locally will compile the closest project defined by a `tsconfig.json`, or you can compile a set of TypeScript files by passing in a glob of files you want. When input files are specified on the command line, `tsconfig.json` files are ignored.
>
> ```sh
> # Run a compile based on a backwards look through the fs for a tsconfig.json
> tsc
>
> # Emit JS for just the index.ts with the compiler defaults
> tsc index.ts
> ```

If you want to include certain files in the compilation, you can use the [`includes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include) field in your project config.

Comment: I am facing this transpilation issue with any kind of file ".ts" file  that I run. Is there any general solution you can provide. While, the solution you provide is correct, is  there any optimized approach through which I can run this .

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76752355/when-i-transpile-my-typescript-file-the-variables-declared-in-let-and-const/76752531#comment135314347_76752531) @JayPathar "Optimized" is a relative term. After you determine what exactly you want to ask, you can [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) which includes those details. (However, please first search for duplicate questions and see [ask] before posting again.)